# Подключение сервиса оплаты ЮКасса на сайт

Tags: laravel

Всем привет, хочу задать вопрос по безопасной сделке от ЮКассы.

В доке указанно 6 пунктов:

```
1. Покупатель и продавец заключают между собой сделку на вашей платформе.
2. Покупатель вносит оговоренную оплату.
3. ЮKassa холдирует («замораживает») оплату на своей стороне.
4. Продавец оказывает покупателю услугу или передает ему товар заявленного качества.
5. Покупатель на вашей платформе сообщает о результатах сделки.
6. Если с товаром или услугой всё хорошо, ЮKassa перечисляет продавцу оплату от покупателя. Если продавец не выполнил свою часть сделки, ЮKassa возвращает внесенную оплату покупателю.
```

Тут все ясно, а как например обработать следующий кейс.

Покупатель оплатил, деньги в холде, продавец отправил товар, покупатель на почте товар забрал и ушел домой, зашел в сервис и нажал на кнопку что с товаром беда, соответственно юкасса вернет деньги покупателю. А продавец окажется без товара и денег.

Думаю для таких вещей нужны свои пункты выдачи?

P.s. без понятия какой тег выставить, поставил Laravel тк делаю оплату именно на этом фрейме

Comment: Вам точно надо не здесь такими вопросами задаваться. Здесь Вам по коду помогут, а не с юридической стороны. Хотите узнать, что юкасса сделает в таком случае и как будет правильно – спросите у них в поддержке.

Answer (score 0):

Пункт 5. Покупатель на вашей платформе сообщает о результатах сделки.
Тут имеется в виду, что покупатель сообщает об этом вам, то есть площадке (а не ЮКассе).

Всеми действиями с платежом вы управляете самостоятельно, отправляя запросы по API в ЮKassa. То есть такие кейсы между продавцом и покупателем вы (как площадка) регулируете самостоятельно - если нужно сделать возврат, отправляете запрос по API. Не нужно - не отправляете.